# Java sonar violation on "Convert this usage of the ternary operator to an "if"/"else" structure"

Tags: java, sonarqube

```
stageIndexingCode = StringUtils.isEmpty(indexOperation) 
                  ? stageIndexingCode 
                  : indexOperation;
```

How can we rewrite this into if else structure?
without creating any warnings.

Note: `stageIndexingCode` is of type `String`

Comment: 1 - disable the warning (`//NOSONAR`, or `@SupressWarnings(...)`)?!, 2 - `if (!...isEmpty(...)) stageIndexingCode = indexOperation; `. Anyway I would avoid, even if not directly, to write `stageIndexCode = stageIndexCode;`

Answer (score 1):

You should make some research about what is a ternary operator.

```
if (StringUtils.isEmpty(indexOperation)) {
    stageIndexingCode = stageIndexingCode;
} else {
    stageIndexingCode =indexOperation;
}
```

shorter form:

```
if (!StringUtils.isEmpty(indexOperation)) {
    stageIndexingCode =indexOperation;
}
```

Comment: OP certainly knows about ternary operator - first suggestion is not considering questions request "without creating any warnings" (I believe)

Comment: first suggestion is the basic convertion of the ternary operator to an if/else structure, but yes, it will probably throw a warning for useless code.

Comment: I mean the author already knows that, it is not the question here! The question is how to write it avoiding the warning from SonarQube!

Comment: well, that's why I put the shorter form.

Comment: "You should make some research about what is a ternary operator." ? I believe it is more about SonarQube...

Comment: original operation is really basic. And converting it is also basic. I express a doubt about OP knowledge.

Comment: "How can we rewrite this into if else structure?" Use the first suggestion -> get a new warning about useless code -> use the second suggestion. Anyway, this discussions is pointles. Let's end it here

Comment: @CarlosHeuberger : So I will go for second suggession.